# Google app engine: creating datastore entity from the post data

Tags: python, google-app-engine, post, google-cloud-datastore

I am working on implementing a small online survey using the google app engine. I've already made the survey itself. What I need now is the possibility to store all the inputs from a person participating in this survey in the database.

The straight forward way to achieve this would be to create an entity with a property for each of the inputs and to create such an entity each time a person submits a filled out survey.

As I have about 30 inputs in my survey, I would like to know whether there is a more elegant or at least a less tedious way to turn the data in the post request into a datastore entity.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WTForms has a GAE extension that can be used to generate forms from models and models from forms.

> With WTForms, your form field HTML can be generated for you, but we
>   let you customize it in your templates. This allows you to maintain
>   separation of code and presentation, and keep those messy parameters
>   out of your python code. Because we strive for loose coupling, you
>   should be able to do that in any templating engine you like, as well.

http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.2/ext.html

```
wtforms.ext.appengine.db.model_form(model, base_class=Form, only=None, exclude=None, field_args=None, converter=None)
```

> Creates and returns a dynamic wtforms.Form class for a given db.Model
>   class. The form class can be used as it is or serve as a base for
>   extended form classes, which can then mix non-model related fields,
>   subforms with other model forms, among other possibilities.

Creating a model based on a form involves creating a form object then passing the POST data to it.

http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/forms.html#the-form-class

> `formdata` – Used to pass data coming from the enduser, usually
>   request.POST or equivalent. formdata should be some sort of
>   request-data wrapper which can get multiple parameters from the form
>   input, and values are unicode strings, e.g. a Werkzeug/Django/WebOb
>   MultiDict

And there is a similar question here: [WTForms error:TypeError: formdata should be a multidict-type wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978986/wtforms-errortypeerror-formdata-should-be-a-multidict-type-wrapper)

e.g.

```
def post(self):
   form = model_form(Ticket)
   form_object = form(formdata=self.request.POST)
```

[from some random example I just found.](http://blog.fruiapps.com/2012/06/Modelforms-for-appengine-models-with-WTForms-and-debugging-with-pdb)

Comment: Just beware that if you expect to do statistics with the responses (averages, sums etc of a column value) you might be better off using cloud sql instead of the datastore. Otherwise you have to deal with agregating data manually and dealing with long results (timeout from front end while processing it etc)

Comment: @Paul Collingwood . Okay thank you. If I understand it correctly, the model_form is used to create a form from a Datastore model. What would I have to do to do it the other way round (making an entity from posted data)